# Volume in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Running a service create with volume mounting and replicas, the volume replicates to all worker nodes, no problem… however the synchronization of a file can only happen on a specific node, e.g. in the swarm node1 when modifying the file in the host can only be seen inside the container within that node1 which is fine as expected but other worker nodes cannot see the file.

I’ve read somewhere that Swarm only come with the standard local driver out of the box. It doesn’t have any awareness of Swarm, and it will just create new volumes for your data on whichever node your service tasks are scheduled on.

I want to add/modify a file within a volume and replicates to every nodes … is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151840/596285

Comment: Thank you @BMitch for now I can leave whatever swarm is currently supporting. not an urgent requirement...